# What to do if alone in B&B and the doorbell rings?

Tags: legal, accommodation, ireland

I am currently staying in a Bed and Breakfast hosted by a family. The doorbell has been ringing intermittently for the past five minutes. The owners are currently attending other business and are unable to answer the door.

**Should I answer the door?**

Notes:

1. The owners mobile phone number is printed on a sign just outside the building
2. The time is 5:33pm

Thoughts:

1. Could be another guest whose magnetic stripe card was lost or wiped
2. Could be a genuine person looking for a room
3. Could be opportunistic thieves

Comment: Answer the door. What if it's a child trying to escape an abductor?  If have have any doubts about it after answering the door, take their photo with your mobile.

Comment: @GayotFow Would a child ring the doorbell or scream "Help I'm being abducted"?

Comment: That might alert the abductor to his whereabouts. So did you answer the door or not?

Comment: @GayotFow I did, I was other thinking and being paranoid.

Comment: Look out the window, take a picture of the people outside and let a vote on StackExchange decide.

Comment: How come you are travelling if you are so afraid of answering the door ? And staying in a B&B ?

Comment: @DumbCoder I am travelling for work purposes.

Answer (score 2):

**I answered the door.** It was a genuine person looking for a room, they did not have a phone and were unable to call the owners. I proceeded to contact the B&B owners who arrived five minutes later.

Comment: +1, all's well that ends well.  But if they are in the B&B overnight, then sleep with one eye open :)